# Grouping arrays and get the last and first array for every group

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

Lets say I have a sample array that looks like this.

[image]

In code output here is what it looks

`[[2131, 2016-01-01, 1:00 PM, FA1], [2131, 2016-01-01, 2:00 PM, FA1], [2131, 2016-01-01, 3:00 PM, FA1], [2132, 2016-01-02, 4:00 PM, FA1].....]`

How can I make this look like this?

[image]

I mean always group the data by the date and get only the last and first set of data for every group

I hope you get my point TYSM

Comment: We see you've removed 3 rows from your table. Are those rows removed on the basis of some logic?

Comment: Yes sir. Lets say grooup the array inside an array based on 1st and second column then get only the 1st and last one. something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. As per the intput you've given I've constructed the array and got the output as desired. Hope it helps.

```
var inputarr = [ [ 2131, "2016-01-01", "1:00 PM", "FA1" ],
        [ 2131, "2016-01-01", "2:00 PM", "FA1" ],
        [ 2131, "2016-01-01", "3:00 PM", "FA1" ],
        [ 2132, "2016-01-02", "4:00 PM", "FA1" ],
        [ 2132, "2016-01-02", "5:00 PM", "FA1" ],
        [ 2132, "2016-01-02", "6:00 PM", "FA1" ],
        [ 2133, "2016-01-03", "7:00 PM", "FA1" ],
        [ 2133, "2016-01-03", "8:00 PM", "FA1" ],
        [ 2133, "2016-01-03", "9:00 PM", "FA1" ] ];

map = {};
for ( var element in inputarr) {
    if (!map[inputarr[element][1]]) {
        map[inputarr[element][1]] = [];
    }
    map[inputarr[element][1]].push(inputarr[element]);
}

output = [];

for ( var key in map) {
    output.push(map[key].shift());
    output.push(map[key].pop());
}

console.log(output);
```

Output:

```
[ [ 2131, '2016-01-01', '1:00 PM', 'FA1' ],
  [ 2131, '2016-01-01', '3:00 PM', 'FA1' ],
  [ 2132, '2016-01-02', '4:00 PM', 'FA1' ],
  [ 2132, '2016-01-02', '6:00 PM', 'FA1' ],
  [ 2133, '2016-01-03', '7:00 PM', 'FA1' ],
  [ 2133, '2016-01-03', '9:00 PM', 'FA1' ] ]
```

Comment: Sir TYSSM for the effort but sir I think this is not javascript

Comment: my bad :) writing pyton code somewhere. Quite simple in JS too. Will edit this with that code in a moment.

Comment: converted the code to JavaScript. Hope it helps you sir.

Comment: tysm sir for the help

Comment: sir looks like your code is the nearest answer can I have a question?

Comment: can I have something like this? group them by 1st and 2nd column and sort the group using the 3rd column like (time in and time out) it will be looked like a daily time record but many time in and out. lets say for example me identity is 2131 (ex.) and I have 5 entries how can I sort it then get the first time in and the last time out?

Comment: you can group by the above method anyway you want just do map[inputarr[element].slice(startIdx, endIdx)].push(inputarr[element]);

Comment: How can I achieve that sir?

Comment: Realy 1st time to this code.Please bear me with this one I hope I can make it anyway sir a big TYSSSSSM

Comment: Sir `startIdx, endIdx` is not define

Comment: The code given above is grouping using just the date. It can be modified to group using columns 1 and 2 together.

Comment: Now considering you have 5 records for 1 employee, for 2 dates as below.

inputarr = [ [ 2131, "2016-01-01", "1:00 PM", "FA1" ],
        [ 2131, "2016-01-01", "2:00 PM", "FA1" ],
        [ 2131, "2016-01-02", "5:00 PM", "FA1" ],
        [ 2131, "2016-01-02", "3:00 PM", "FA1" ],
        [ 2131, "2016-01-02", "2:00 PM", "FA1" ] ];

Comment: We can see that row 3,4,5 are for Jan 2, 2016 and are in wrong order of time. To sort them we can use the below functions.

Comment: 1. Prepare the map
map = {};
for ( var element in inputarr) {
    if (!map[inputarr[element][0] + ' ' + inputarr[element][1]]) {
        map[inputarr[element][0] + ' ' + inputarr[element][1]] = [];
    }
    map[inputarr[element][0] + ' ' + inputarr[element][1]]
            .push(inputarr[element]);
}

Comment: output map will be :
{ '2131 2016-01-01': 
   [ [ 2131, '2016-01-01', '1:00 PM', 'FA1' ],
     [ 2131, '2016-01-01', '2:00 PM', 'FA1' ] ],
  '2131 2016-01-02': 
   [ [ 2131, '2016-01-02', '5:00 PM', 'FA1' ],
     [ 2131, '2016-01-02', '3:00 PM', 'FA1' ],
     [ 2131, '2016-01-02', '2:00 PM', 'FA1' ] ] }

Comment: 2. To sort we can use below code:

var getTime = function (stringTime) {
    var hoursMins = stringTime.split(' ')[0].split(':');
    hours = parseInt(hoursMins[0]);
    minutes = parseInt(hoursMins[1]);
    return {
        "hours" : hours,
        "mins" : minutes
    };
};

for ( var key in map) {
    map[key].sort(function (a, b) {
        aTime = getTime(a[2]);
        bTime = getTime(b[2]);
        if (aTime.hours == bTime.hours) {
            return aTime.minutes - bTime.minutes;
        }
        return aTime.hours - bTime.hours;
    });
}

Comment: console.log(map["2131 2016-01-02"]);

Checking what is the sorted output for Jan 2, we get: 

[ [ 2131, '2016-01-02', '2:00 PM', 'FA1' ],
  [ 2131, '2016-01-02', '3:00 PM', 'FA1' ],
  [ 2131, '2016-01-02', '5:00 PM', 'FA1' ] ]

Comment: Basically what is done is written a anonymous function to compare times and sort by time.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
let arr = [[2131, "2016-01-01", "1:00 PM", "FA1"], [2131, "2016-01-01", "2:00 PM", "FA1"], [2131, "2016-01-01", "3:00 PM", "FA1"]
            , [2132, "2016-01-02", "4:00 PM", "FA1"], [2132, "2016-01-02", "5:00 PM", "FA1"], [2132, "2016-01-02", "6:00 PM", "FA1"]
            , [2133, "2016-01-03", "7:00 PM", "FA1"], [2133, "2016-01-03", "8:00 PM", "FA1"], [2133, "2016-01-03", "9:00 PM", "FA1"]]
let startMap = {};
let endMap = {};
let dateArray = [];
let resultArray = [];

for(let element of arr){
    console.log(element);
    if(startMap[element[1]] === undefined){
        startMap[element[1]] = element;
        dateArray.push(element[1]);
    }
    endMap[element[1]] = element;
}

for(let date of dateArray){
    resultArray.push(startMap[date]);
    resultArray.push(endMap[date]);
}
console.log(resultArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this ES6 script:

```js
const data = [
    [2131, "2016-01-01", "1:00 PM", "FA1"], 
    [2131, "2016-01-01", "2:00 PM", "FA1"], 
    [2131, "2016-01-01", "3:00 PM", "FA1"],
    [2132, "2016-01-02", "4:00 PM", "FA1"],
    [2132, "2016-01-02", "5:00 PM", "FA1"],
    [2132, "2016-01-02", "6:00 PM", "FA1"], 
    [2133, "2016-01-03", "7:00 PM", "FA1"],
    [2133, "2016-01-03", "8:00 PM", "FA1"],
    [2133, "2016-01-03", "9:00 PM", "FA1"]
];

const result = [].concat(...data.reduce( (acc, a) =>
    acc.set(a[1], (acc.get(a[1]) || []).slice(0, 1).concat([a]))
, new Map).values());

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Explanation

`reduce` is used with an empty `Map` as start value. That `Map` is then populated with the date as key, and the matching original values as array values for each key. With `slice` only the first entry of such an array is maintained while the new entry is added to it. This way there will always only be at the most 2 values in each array.

Once `reduce` has returned the final `Map`, the values are extracted from it with `values`, and spread as arguments to `concat` which will make it a flat array again.